# How to remove longer element in each group in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
name1 name2
abc   def 
abc   de
xy    cdf
xy    che
mnp   qpr
mnp   qprt
mnp   qp
```

I want to remove the longer `name2` for each group of `name1`. More specifically, for each group of `name1`, the first two characters of the shorter `name2` should be the same as the longer one. Moreover, the number of row of each group should be 2, i.e., groups with rows more than 2 are not considered.

Here is the expected output:(only def is removed)

```
name1 name2
abc   de
xy    cdf
xy    che
mnp   qpr
mnp   qprt
mnp   qp
```

How to write the SQL command?

Comment: why you are not removing "mnp   qprt" and "mnp   qpr"

Comment: @PSK because there are 3 rows of `mnp`.

Comment: @John . . . "Moreover, the number of row of each group should be 2, i.e., groups with rows more than 2 are not considered."  Your results don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT name1, name2
FROM (
  SELECT name1, name2,       
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name1) AS grp_cnt,
         s.similar_cnt 
  FROM mytable t
  OUTER APPLY 
  (
      SELECT COUNT(*) similar_cnt
      FROM mytable 
      WHERE name1 = t.name1 AND name2 <> t.name2 AND t.name2 LIKE name2 + '%'
  ) AS s    
) AS x
WHERE x.grp_cnt > 2 OR x.similar_cnt = 0
```

[**Demo here**](https://rextester.com/MEZU15415)

Explanation:

- `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name1)` counts the population of each `name1` group of records
- `OUTER APPLY` is used to check for records having the same `name1` and  *similar* `name2` values. Similar here means same as the other one but shorter.

You can easily adjust similarity checking by fiddling with the `WHERE` clause of the `OUTER APPLY` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

use `dense_rank()` and `union all`

```
 select name1,name2 from 
(
select *,dense_rank()over(partition by name1 order by len(name2) desc ) rn,
 count(*) over(partition by name1) as cn from @table
) t where t.rn=1 and cn=2
union all
select name1,name2 from 
(
select t.*, count(*) over(partition by name1) as cn from @table t
) t where cn>2
```

output

```
name1   name2
abc     def
xy      cdf
xy      che
mnp     qpr
mnp     qprt
mnp     qp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following.

```
;with cte as
(
     select name1,
     name2, 
     dense_rank() over(partition by name1 order by len(name2) ) rn, 
     count(*) over(partition by name1) ct
     from @table
)

select name1,name2 from cte
where rn=1 or ct > 2
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/JNX91061)

**Output**

```
+-------+-------+
| name1 | name2 |
+-------+-------+
| abc   | de    |
+-------+-------+
| mnp   | qp    |
+-------+-------+
| mnp   | qpr   |
+-------+-------+
| mnp   | qprt  |
+-------+-------+
| xy    | cdf   |
+-------+-------+
| xy    | che   |
+-------+-------+
```

**Edit**

Dense rank will assign rank to the to the rows having same name incrementally. Name with more length will get higher rank for the group and name2 with same length in a group will get same rank.

Count for each group of name is being stored in `ct` column. So it will help to ignore the records having count > 2

Using `CTE` for simplifying the query, otherwise we can do it without `CTE` also.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Thank you for your solution and demo, PSK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a select statement :

```
with t(name1, name2) as
(
 select 'abc','def'  union all 
 select 'abc','de'   union all
 select 'xy','cdf'   union all
 select 'xy','che'   union all
 select 'mnp','qpr'  union all
 select 'mnp','qprt' union all
 select 'mnp','qp' 
), t2 as
( 
select name1, max(name2) as name2
  from t 
 group by name1, substring(name2,1,2)
 having count(*) = 2
)  
select * from t except 
select * from t2;

name1   name2
-----   -----
abc     de
xy      cdf
xy      che
mnp     qpr
mnp     qprt
mnp     qp
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/AQGRGZ26987)</kbd>

Comment: error : `'substr' is not a recognized built-in function name.`